# Angular: jQuery not working after route navigation

Tags: angular

I'm building frontend app with Angular (version 4 currently).
After user login I call:

```
this._router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
```

But my theme controls not working (sidebar can't be hidden etc.).
But when I do page reload in browser everything works correctly.
What can be a problem here. 
project is created with angular-cli and all js scripts are referenced in .angular-cli.json file.

Comment: Include your component code, so people can see what's happening.